# Displaying a NavigationBar, inside a NavigationView, inside a TabView, after a NavigationLink. SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview, tabview, navigationlink

I'm making an App in which user needs to Log In and after that take me to a TabView in which I have 3 different views (Navigation Views).

The problem is after I Log In, and use a NavigationLink to send me to the TabView, to display me the 3 different views, in which I have NavigationBarTitles; it also creates another (empty) NavigationBarTitle over mine.

Already tried to use the usual method of: Inside this individual views, eliminate the NavigationView property, as it would usually work, but not in this case.

LOGIN VIEW

```
import SwiftUI

struct LogInView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink (destination: ContentView()) {
                    Text("Log In")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(15)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Log In View")
        }
    }
}

struct LogInView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LogInView()
    }
}
```

TABVIEW

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){

            DetailView()
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

DETAIL VIEW

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hi")
                Text("Hi")
                Text("Hi")
            }.navigationBarTitle("DetailView")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView()
    }
}
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhLLk.png)

Answer (score 1):

A child view should not be wrapped in a `NavigationView` if its parent (or its parent's parent..) is wrapped in one. You simply have two `NavigationView`s on the photo shown, so remove the one in DetailView, it will still have on inherited from LogInView:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hi")
            Text("Hi")
            Text("Hi")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("DetailView")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've try this before, but the problem is that I took away the "empty NavigationBarTitle", but it doesn't display my "DetailView NavigationBarTitle" either. It just gets empty again, but with the NavigationBarTitleSpace.

Answer (score 0):

You may optimize everything in ContentView not the detailView. Although the reasoning is alright in your current work, the logics behind presentation may involve some tweaks.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
@State private var selection = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection){

        DetailView()
            .font(.title)
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("first")
                    Text("First")
                }
            }
            .tag(0)

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("DetailView", displayMode: .inline).navigationBarHidden(true)

}
}


struct DetailView: View {
var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hi")
            Text("Hi")
            Text("Hi")
        }

}
}
```

Comment: The logic here is correct, but the problem is that when I add more than one "Detail View" in my "TabView" I cannot change the NavigationBarTitleText, for each "DetailView".

Comment: you can add an array for the title names: `navigationBarTitle(DetailViewNames[selection]), display: .inline)`